# Normal.dotm MS Word Template file for custom templates

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, templates

My company has a set of custom MS Office templates, including a modified Normal.dotm file. These are placed in the "personal" templates folder, however when you try to save a file you get prompts related to the Normal.dotm file.

My suspicion is that the second "Personal" Normal.dotm file is conflicting with the  main Normal.dotm file somehow when the user tries to save.

Has anyone else run into this?

Answer (score 0):

There should be one Normal.dotm file (the default template Word uses) - your company has probably altered the default (and it's fairly common with things like company details in footnotes etc). They have probably marked it as read only, so trying to save it can not overwrite the template, and it prompts you where else to save. It sounds like you're saving a different template to use - I suggest you call it Normal1.dotm, and then set it as the default template in Word's settings. This should ideally only affect your user profile, and the company's Normal.dotm file can stay as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to fix it:

1. First of all, you should know where your default Normal.dotm is located. You could google it or install any search utility. Personally, I use Agent Ransack for years.
2. Then, find this default Normal.dotm and rename it to something different (some people just delete it).
3. Place you customized Normal.dotm in this folder, instead of old Normal.dotm.